# cell properties set in viewcontroller do not reflect

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I've got a subclass of `UITableViewCell`. I want to create a shadow on the labels dependent on the brightness of the image on the background. However, this image is set in the `TableViewController`. When `awakeFromNib` is called, `self.backImage.iamge` is `nil`. I tried implementing `initWithStyle` in the subclass itself but it logged nil as well.

When the cell is eventually loaded tho, the image is displayed.

Is there an event that happends when the cell is updated trough

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So your table view controller is setting the background image for the cell? I assume it does this in cellForRowAtIndexPath after dequeueing the cell?

If so, try creating a method on your custom cell that sets the label shadow. Call the method after dequeueing the cell and setting the background image. If necessary, pass a parameter in the method that tells how dark to make the shadow.